# How do I run an exponential nls with seasonal dummies in R?

Tags: r, regression, nls

I'm having trouble with running an nls regression with seasonal dummies in R.
I'm able to do it without the seasonal dummies, but not with. 
This is what I have so far:

```
year=floor(time(lsts))
> month=round(time(lsts)-year,4)
> month.f=factor(month)
> dummies=model.matrix(~month.f)
hotdogNLS<-nls(lsts~beta1/(1+exp(beta2+beta3*t)),start=list(beta1=2500,beta2=0.5,beta3=-0.5),trace=F)
```

> summary(hotdogNLS)

```
Formula: lsts ~ beta1/(1 + exp(beta2 + beta3 * t))

Parameters:
        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
beta1  2.030e+03  5.874e+01   34.55   <2e-16 ***
beta2  1.146e+00  5.267e-02   21.76   <2e-16 ***
beta3 -1.116e-02  7.668e-04  -14.56   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 192.3 on 333 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations to convergence: 8 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 2.054e-06
```

How do I include seasonal dummies? 
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by a dummy here? Would the parameters be evaluated completely separately for each dummy value or would you have one or a few parameters only depending the dummy value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think dummies are implemented for `nls` like they are in `glm` due to the fact that "formula" for `nls` is a real mathematical formula unlike for `glm`.

You can nevertheless specify if a parameter must be assessed separately for each class of a dummy:

```
    data(cars)
    # define the dummy
    cars$dummy <- as.factor(LETTERS[1:5])
    # code as 0/1 the dummy with a column per dummy level
    cars$A<- as.numeric(cars$dummy=="A")
    cars$B<- as.numeric(cars$dummy=="B")
    cars$C<- as.numeric(cars$dummy=="C")
    cars$D<- as.numeric(cars$dummy=="D")
    cars$E<- as.numeric(cars$dummy=="E")

    # precise in the formula where the dummy level should play out
    # here in the intercept:
    model <- nls(dist~beta1*speed^beta2+beta3*A+beta4*B+beta5*C+beta6*D+beta7*E,data=cars)

    model

    Nonlinear regression model
      model: dist ~ beta1 * speed^beta2 + beta3 * A + beta4 * B + beta5 * C + beta6 * D + beta7 * E
      data: cars
      beta1   beta2   beta3   beta4   beta5   beta6   beta7 
      0.2069  1.8580  2.8266  5.3973 13.0002  9.3539  2.5361 
      residual sum-of-squares: 10040

      Number of iterations to convergence: 8 
      Achieved convergence tolerance: 4.924e-06
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Except that when I try to run the nls, it asks for start values - do you have any idea how to come up with these? When I try to use start values, I get an error: step factor reduced below minFactor.

Comment: For the start values you can usually ignore the message and do it with the default. But if it complains further it might be because you are trying to estimate too many things for your data. Make sure then to set start values that are reasonable. Try the to ask less from NLS(less groups, less beta). If you cannot fix it on your own ask an other question as it is a completely different issue. Remember to close this one accepting an answer and up voting answers that helps you

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `factor` to subset the estimated coefficient like `alpha[dummy]`.

```
data(cars)
cars$dummy <- as.factor(LETTERS[1:5])

nls(dist ~ alpha[dummy] + beta1*speed^beta2, data=cars, start=list(beta1=.2, beta2=3, alpha=rep(10, nlevels(cars$dummy))))
#Nonlinear regression model
#  model: dist ~ alpha[dummy] + beta1 * speed^beta2
#   data: cars
#  beta1   beta2  alpha1  alpha2  alpha3  alpha4  alpha5 
# 0.2069  1.8580  2.8264  5.3971 13.0000  9.3537  2.5359 
# residual sum-of-squares: 10040
#
#Number of iterations to convergence: 12 
#Achieved convergence tolerance: 2.372e-06
```

Answer (score 0):

@cmbarbu's answer of setting up dummies by hand should work, but this can be done more easily with `nlme::gnls()` and the `params` argument:

```r
nls(lsts ~ beta1/(1+exp(beta2+beta3*t)),
    start = list(beta1=2500,beta2=0.5,beta3=-0.5),
    params = beta1 + beta2 + beta3 ~ season
)
```

(see `?nlme::gnls` for details, how to specify different linear submodels for different nonlinear parameters, etc.)