# force negative slope linear regression r

Tags: r

Is it possible to force the lm function to produce only negative slopes? Or even better could one fit a model like this:

```
alpha + beta * exp(-theta ...)
```

Having data with one numeric and one factor feature?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Force in what way? What if there are positive slopes? Also, your formula can be used in nls, non-linear regression.

Comment: yes thanks I cam across nls in this context but did not figure how to implement the formula ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `abs` inside the formula like:

```
set.seed(7)
n  <- 1e5
x  <- data.frame(a=rnorm(n), b=abs(rnorm(n)))
x$a  <- x$a + exp(-1*x$b)


nls(a ~ alpha + beta * exp(-abs(theta) * b), data=x, start=list(alpha=0, beta=1, theta=1))
#Nonlinear regression model
#  model: a ~ alpha + beta * exp(-abs(theta) * b)
#   data: x
#   alpha     beta    theta 
#-0.02327  1.02176  0.96014 
# residual sum-of-squares: 99903
#
#Number of iterations to convergence: 2 
#Achieved convergence tolerance: 3.156e-09
```

In case you also want to include a `factor`you could do it like:

```
x$c  <- factor(c("f1", "f2"))
nls(a ~ alpha[c] + beta * exp(-abs(theta) * b), data=x, start=list(alpha=c(0,0), beta=1, theta=1))
#Nonlinear regression model
#  model: a ~ alpha[c] + beta * exp(-abs(theta) * b)
#   data: x
#  alpha1   alpha2     beta    theta 
#-0.02570 -0.02076  1.02175  0.96026 
# residual sum-of-squares: 99903
#
#Number of iterations to convergence: 2 
#Achieved convergence tolerance: 3.527e-09
```

Comment: This is amazing thanks. Let us say I also have a factor c - how can I bake this into the above formula please? The lm formula would be: a ~ b + c

Comment: Guess it would be a long wounded way like this?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29176766/how-do-i-run-an-exponential-nls-with-seasonal-dummies-in-r

Comment: Thanks this doe not converge I guess - getting Error in numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env) : Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model. May have to use explicit dummies as mentioned in the link?

Comment: yeah sure - sorry I use my real data (-:

Comment: @cs0815 Maybe you have to find better starting coefficients or change to `algorithm="port"`. Sometimes it helps when turning `trace` on.