# Non-linear Least Squares with dummies

Tags: r, optimization

I am trying to run a non-linear least-squares regression, but with dummies in order to leave out a certain range of the distribution (9<=x<=11).  (sort of line in this example : [How do I run an exponential nls with seasonal dummies in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29176766/how-do-i-run-an-exponential-nls-with-seasonal-dummies-in-r) )

I run into two problems:

1. When i create dummies for t=9, 10, 11 I expect to capture the values of y at those points (101, 97, 87). And to get a curve that sort of follows along the rest of the points. But instead I get a curve that is significantly lower than the points.
2. In the future I would like to run a simulation and test what range of points left out would best fit the rest of the curve. How can I re-write my code to not have to manually create c, d, e and re-write the function each time.

Thanks for your help.

```r
y <-c(220, 160, 145, 127, 117, 114, 106, 100, 101, 97, 87, 70, 64, 65)
t <- seq(1,14,1)

# starting values:
lm <-lm(log(y) ~ log(t))

# 
y <-c(220, 160, 145, 127, 117, 114, 106, 100, 101, 97, 87, 70, 64, 65)
t <- seq(1,14,1)
c <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
d <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
e <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)

# starting values:
lm <-lm(log(y) ~ log(t))

# Exp. Least-Squares minimization:
func <-function(pars) {
  a <- pars["a"]
  b <- pars["b"]
  c <- pars["c"]
  d <- pars["d"]
  e <- pars["e"]

  fitted <- a*exp(b*t) + c + d + e
  sum((y-fitted)^2)  
} 

a <-lm$coefficients[[1]]
b <-lm$coefficients[[2]]
c <- 0
d <- 0
e <- 0

result <- optim(c(a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d, e=e), func)

# final parameters:
a <- result$par["a"]
b <- result$par["b"]
c <- result$par["c"]
d <- result$par["d"]
e <- result$par["e"]


# predict values:
pred <- a*exp(b*t)
dat = data.frame(y=y, t=t, pred=pred)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=t, y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data=dat, aes(x=t, y=pred), color='blue')
```

Comment: It should be `pred <- a*exp(b*t)+ c + d + e`.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. This explains my first question. How do I deal with the second?

Comment: That is a difficult question. I would instead focus on robust nonlinear regression.

Comment: What do you mean robust nonlinear regression?

Comment: You mean finding the most robust nl regression and forgetting about leaving out that range? Unfortunately, leaving our a certain range is an integral part of my methodology, so i cannot.

Comment: Is the range defined? E.g., is their a fixed window width for the gap?

Comment: Let's say yes. The range would change in each loop. But I can build a loop around it once I know how to automate it for a fixed width.

Comment: Well, I think getting something good out of that is more of a challenge then you imagine, but in principle it's easy: Just remove d and e from your function and add some subsetting `y <- y[t < p | t > p + w]` (and the same for t), where p is a parameter to be fitted and w is a fixed value. Of course, you probably should specify some bounds for p.

Comment: However, I would probably try modelling the disturbance instead.

Comment: Hi @Roland. Thanks for your help. I've taken it to heart and I might have another solution that will not require me to add dummies. I've posted it here. Would you be able to look at that question too?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57852749/nls-optimization-with-constraints-equal-area-under-the-curve